# conio.h for ubuntu linux

Tags: c++, termios

I have tried simple terminal snake game

I have used this code  as a replacement for getch() from conio.h 
but i have a problem that when i press a key the snake moves only one move 
i need it to move according to a single char input until it receive a command to change direction:

any help with that ? my google search reached a dead end

link to code
 [https://github.com/mu7ammad-3li/Cpp_language/blob/master/Projects/Mini_Projects/snake/snake.cpp]

```
char getch_(int echo) 
{
  char ch;
  initTermios(echo);
  ch = getchar();
  resetTermios();
  return ch;
}
char getch(void) 
{
  return getch_(0);
}
char getche(void) 
{
  return getch_(1);
}
```

Comment: Use a loop that "draws" over and over, while *polling* for keys?

Comment: Also, initializing and resetting the terminal for each `getch_` call seems wasteful.

Comment: Lastly, you might want to consider a library such as *ncurses*, which exists on all major platforms (including Linux, macOS, *and* Windows).